# Where is the 'head' on infested chargers?

Tags: warframe

Is it possible to head shot chargers?

When I have the headshots bonus I'd like to be able to complete it. I'm not sure that's possible with chargers.

If so, where is the head?

Comment: They do have a head and it's possible.

Comment: Easy way to get headshots is shotgun.  Lots of projectiles makes hitting the head statistically likely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the head is located level with the body (not on top, but in front of it). What I do is just think of it like a wolf, because (unless I'm seeing it wrong, which isn't hard to believe with the chaos on infested levels) generally the body lines up, basically just shoot at the front side when it's coming at you, I think it works.